# Is it possible to access a variable directly from helper module in layouts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been trying to access a variable from helper in layouts.

The SessionHelper class:

```
module SessionsHelper
@@c=0
```

I have been trying to access it directly without any method in a layout which comes under views.

I am getting:

> unintialized class variable error.

Answer (score 0):

All instance variables in views came from controllers by convention.

And by the way class variables are [banned by codestyle](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#no-class-vars)

You can make method in your helper, something like:

```
module SomeHelper
  def some_variable
    smth
  end
end
```

And then use `some_variable` in view.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access `@@c` in your views. You could do something like this:

```
# session helper
module SessionsHelper
  # use a global variable
  $c = 0
end

# in views
<p><%= $c %></p>
```

Or one of the best way would be to use `method`

```
# session helper
module SessionsHelper
  $c = 0

  def set_value_of_c(value)
    $c = value
  end

  def c
    $c
  end
end

# in views
<p><%= c %></p>
# => <p>0</p>

## Change value
<% set_value_of_c(4) %>
<p><%= c %></p>
# => <p>4</p>
```